# Crystal Reports - Standard Deviation of data from 2 sources

Tags: arrays, crystal-reports, shared, standard-deviation

I have 2 subreports that return data from customer satisfaction surveys. One for `Incidents Logged`and one for `Requests Logged`.

Both have the same 5 questions.

I need to combine the results to find the standard deviation for each question to present in a main report.

eg.

`In report 1 field {usr_incidentsurveyquestion1.ubr_rank} gives results 4,3,4,4,5,3
    In report 2 field {usr_requestsurveyquestion1.ubr_rank} gives results 3,4,5,4,3`

so in the main report I need 4,3,4,4,5,3,3,4,5,4,3

I've hit a brick wall trying to use a shared array.

Is this possible? Any pointers appreciated.

Edit----------------------------------------------------------

```
whileprintingrecords;
shared numbervar Array IncSurvey; 
shared numbervar n; 
n:=n+1; 
redim preserve Incsurvey[n]; 
Incsurvey[n] :={usr_incidentsurveyquestion1.ubr_rank};
```

Comment: how you are getting the digits...in a group or your filed is printing the array of digits

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The digits are coming from the field.

Comment: Shared arrray is the good option what problem you faced?

Comment: I'm pretty new to Crystal so was struggling with the syntax. It seems to expect a string value?

Comment: can you paste the formula let me check

Comment: whileprintingrecords;
shared numbervar Array IncSurvey;
shared numbervar n;
n:=n+1;
redim preserve Incsurvey[n];
Incsurvey[n]  :={usr_incidentsurveyquestion1.ubr_rank};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok by seeing your question and formula looks like you are not using your formula coorectly:

in sub report 1 use your formula and place in the group or detail whereever you are placing the field so that every data will be added up

```
whileprintingrecords;
shared StringVar Array IncSurvey1; 

Incsurvey1 :=Incsurvey1 + totext({usr_incidentsurveyquestion1.ubr_rank});
1
```

If the whole string is coming as one value then use as below:

```
whileprintingrecords1;
shared StringVar Array IncSurvey; 

Incsurvey1 :=totext({usr_incidentsurveyquestion1.ubr_rank});
1
```

Repeat the same for second sub report aswell.

Now in main report go to the section that is coming after the sub report section and write below in formula:

```
   shared StringVar Array IncSurvey1;  //sub report 1
   shared StringVar Array IncSurvey2;  //sub report 2

 Join(IncSurvey1+IncSurvey2,",")
```

Comment: When I do this I get the error: "The result of a formula cannot be an array"

Comment: Sorry, still get the error when I try to save the 1st formula in the subreport.

Comment: ok I thought error in last formula... changed my first and second formula code.. now there will be no error

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much! Really appreciate the help.

Used in conjunction with:

```
Stringvar Array convert := Split({@Array},",");


Numbervar Array numbers;
Redim numbers[Ubound(convert)];


Numbervar i;
for i := 1 to Ubound(convert) do (
  numbers[i] := ToNumber(convert[i])
);


stddev(numbers);
```

to fully solve my problem.